# Operator IN VBA excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Could you help me please? I have tried to solve my problem for about 6 hours.
I have one table and there are 4 columns.

Columns:
Nio ,checked,date,time

I need to get data from the first and second columns, where I have to compare it by date and time.

I wanted to use the operator IN but excel gives me the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Thanks for help.

```
strQueryQ7DrLeftElox = 
"((Select nio,checked 
FROM q7_dr_left_elox_incoming_inspection 
where date >= '" & sDateFrom & "' AND date <= '" & sDateTo & "') IN   (Select nio,checked from q7_dr_left_elox_incoming_inspection WHERE time = '19:55:06'))"
```

Comment: `((select ...) IN (select ...))` is not a valid SQL query, and it's not related to VBA or Excel.

Comment: Can an admin please remove the "Excel" and "vba" tags? This question has nothing to do with either.

Answer (score 3):

Both select statements query the same table, so simplify it by adding one more condition in the 1st query's `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT nio,checked 
FROM q7_dr_left_elox_incoming_inspection 
WHERE date >= '" & sDateFrom & "' AND date <= '" & sDateTo & "'
AND time = '19:55:06'
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I need get data from date to date and from time to time but If I used it like you wrote so I got result not good...I have excel table where I have to choose from date to date and from time to time and I need to get first result order by date and then order by time from first result   for example: from 20.8.2018 to 21.8.2018 and from 08:00:00 to 18:00:00

Comment: I wrote the query with the logic you had in your query to fix the syntax error. If you have a new requirement post a new question where you describe what you want, providing sample data and expected results.